# EF Core - Incorrect string value

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I am using EF to update a field in my MySql DB and ran across the issue of attempting to save data that is not allowable due to collation. For example, ^âÂêÊîÎôÔûÛŵŷ has characters outside the column with character set of latin1.

Running an update/insert with above example I get the exception:
The database update did not take place due to..Incorrect string value

I know what the problem is, but I don't want to keep the characters, the data being provided is usually via UI which would often control what is passed in, however it is also callable by API allowing whatever data the caller would like to send. In the above case, I would like to drop those characters or just replace with a  question mark, basically ignore them.

This system already exists in an older language and the rule to (silently..) ignore them exists, I need the error not to be raised and for it to save what it can. I have seen how I can modify the statements for this, or how I can modify the string data coming in. I have 1000s of these. Is there another method to achieve this?